# How do I set a String variable using inputText in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a flow.xml file that's calling a method on a bean. I just want to have a string that I get from a textbox passed in as a parameter to the method. I've added a h:inputText to my xhtml page, but I can't get it to set a String variable in the corresponding flow. What is the simplest possible way I can get a value from a textbox into a flowscope String variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SomeBean{
String val;
  //getters & setters
  public String foo(){
    System.out.println(val);
    return "SUCCESS";
  }
}
```

xhtml

```
    <h:form>
      <h:inputtext value="#{someBean.val}"/>
      <h:commandButton action="#{someBean.foo}"/>
    </h:form>
```

as html it will render a html form with a textbox and a submit button on licking button it will call `foo()` and text from txtbox will get binded to `val`

Answer (score 0):

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) facesContext.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{flowScope.myBean}").getValue(facesContext);
String val = myBean.GetBeanProperty();
```

Here you should
[more examples.](http://wiki.foochal.org/index.php/Using_JSF_with_Spring_Webflow#Access_your_flow_scope_bean_from_FacesContext.3F)